# Como separar cada sequência de números iguais de uma string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Como faço split de uma string de numeros?
Por exemplo `'233'` para obter `['2','33']`.

Sendo que os valores dados podem variar, por exemplo `'44446'` e dar `['4444','6']`
ou `'2345'` e dar `['2','3','4','5']`.

Ou seja, dar split sempre que o numero for diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que pensar como é feito e escrever o código - 
deve dar para fazer com expressções regulares, ou 
fazer em uma linha só com técnicas de map/reduce  - 
mas o código explícito em algumas linhas fica bem legível:

```
def separate_digits(line):
    result = []
    chain = ""
    last_digit = None
    for digit in line:
        if last_digit != digit:
            if chain:
                result.append(chain)
            chain = ""
        chain += digit
        last_digit = digit
    result.append(chain)
    return result
```

E essa aqui é a forma em uma linha com "reduce" - só para fins de entretenimento :-) - fica também um exemplo didático de "nem tudo que pode ser feito em uma linha *deve* ser feito em uma linha"

```
reduce((lambda previous, digit: [digit] if not previous else (((previous.__setitem__(-1, previous[-1] + digit) if previous[-1][-1] == digit else previous.append(digit)), previous)[1]) ), list("44445552"), [])
```

**update**
Olha tem uma outra forma usando o fato de strings em Python terem o método "strip" bem completo - talvez fique mais fácil de entender legível:

```
def separate_strip(line):
    result = []
    while line:
        digits = (len(line) - len(line.lstrip(line[0]))) * line[0]
        result.append(digits)
        line = line.lstrip(line[0])
    return result
```

Então, em português seria: "enquanto houver elementos na linha: 
( tome a (diferença do tamanho da linha atual e do tamanho da linha removendo
os dígitos iguais ao primeiro) e adicione esse tanto de dígitos igual ao primeiro à resposta; remova o primeiro dígito e os demais iguais a ele) "

Vale notar que só é possível por que as strings tem o método 'lstrip' que remove só do lado esquerdo de uma string todos os caractéres passados.

Comment: sim isto dá tudo bem, mas nao haveria uma maneira mais simples de fazer isto??

Comment: O comptuador vai fazer o que você mandar - e nesse caso, você tem que dar o passo a passo. Essa solução é simples - dá para fazer ela parecer mais simples, se eu eliminar a variável "start" e usar um dígito falso para começar  a contagem - vou atualizar

Comment: Sim está melhor :) tem razão, até é bem simples obrigada !